# Object Needed for "Set n = ..." within a loop

Tags: vba, excel

```
j = 2

Do While PA.Cells(j, 1) <> ""

    Set n = (Cells(j, 50).End(xlDown).Rows.Count) - 2

    If Cells(j, 50) <> "" Then

    Range(Cells(j, 50), Cells(j, 145)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(j, 50), Cells(j + n, 145))

    End If

    j = j + 1

Loop
```

I am receiving an object needed error on line "Set n = ..."

I am not sure how to solve this.  If the "Set n = " value needs to be outside the loop then, how can I go about changing the n value when for each j the n is different?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), The `Set` command is only used for objects, not basic data types, or variants.  In this case `n` is being used as a integer (or long), but might actually be a variant.  As such, `Set` is not needed, and will raise an error.